# Getting name of google places API (Place Search) for my current location

Tags: android, google-places-api, reverse-geocoding, location-based-service

I am making an android app, in which I will use the name of current location to search its details over wikipedia. for e.g. If I am in Madame Tussauds, First I ll get the current location coordinates then after reverse geocoding, it's info will be searched over wikipedia and displayed in my app.

I have my current location coordinates but the problem is when I reverse geocode the coordinates, I don't get the place name. for e.g. for coordinates **33.651826, 73.156593**, when I reverse geocode, I get **Park Road, Pakistan** where as the name of the place is **COMSATS Institute of Information Technology**.

I get  **COMSATS Institute of Information Technology** in Google Places API (Place Search) in Name node. So is there a way I can use Google Places API's name node for my current location name rather than any place search or other features?

Or is there any way I can get the place name using lat lon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a GoogleApiClient object and then call this method

```
private void guessCurrentPlace() {
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace( mGoogleApiClient, null );
result.setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult( PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces ) {

        PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood = likelyPlaces.get( 0 );
        String content = "";
        if( placeLikelihood != null && placeLikelihood.getPlace() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty( placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName() ) )
            content = "Most likely place: " + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName() + "\n";
        if( placeLikelihood != null )
            content += "Percent change of being there: " + (int) ( placeLikelihood.getLikelihood() * 100 ) + "%";
        mTextView.setText( content );

        likelyPlaces.release();
    }
});
}
```

Reference: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/google-play-services-using-the-places-api--cms-23715

Answer (score 2):

The [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/), introduced in [Google Play services 7.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html), offers an API around getting the [current place](https://developers.google.com/places/android/current-place) using [PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceDetectionApi.html#getCurrentPlace(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceFilter)). That method uses the user's current location and then returns a list of likely places for the user to be at. You can then use [Place.getName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getName()) to retrieve the name of the location and display it to the user.

If you want the user to pick a location from around them (rather than choosing the topmost result for them), you can use the [Place Picker UI](https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker).